# Cross request does not return files correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest

I want to send query to my backend server via a proxy script. But it does not return files correctly.

```
public class HttpWebRequestRunner : IWebRequestRunner
{
    public HttpWebResponse Run(string backendUri)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(backendUri);

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

        return response;
    }
}
```

My backend server is closed to internet so I send parameters my Asp.Net Mvc application. And it send request to backend server.

Backend server is returning file for this request: `http://10.0.2.1/Employee/CV/1445`

Inmy mvc controller I use this:

```
 public class PersonController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult GetCv(int id)
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = new HttpWebResponse();

            HttpWebResponse webResponse = response.run("http://10.0.2.1/Employee/CV/1445");

            context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = wbResponse.ContentType;

            webResponse.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream);

            // write result...
        }       
    }
```

Now

if I send request to backend from browser this url   `http://10.0.2.1/Employee/CV/1445` it returns **1445.pdf** file

But If I send request via prox app like this `http://localhost:22414/Person/GetCv/1445` 
this returns a file named **file** but not pdf extension.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File names are in header info. `webResponse.Headers["Content-Disposition"]`. So you have to use like this:

```
 context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Set(
     "Content-Disposition", 
     webResponse.Headers.Get("Content-Disposition"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to relay the `Content-Disposition` HTTP header as well.